# Unknown html tag ion-breadcrumbs, the tag is not recognized by ionic-angular project

Tags: angular, breadcrumbs, ionic7

[ionic breadcrumbs doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/breadcrumbs)

```
<ion-breadcrumbs>
    <ion-breadcrumb href="#home">Home</ion-breadcrumb>
    <ion-breadcrumb href="#electronics">Electronics</ion-breadcrumb>
    <ion-breadcrumb href="#cameras">Cameras</ion-breadcrumb>
    <ion-breadcrumb href="#film">Film</ion-breadcrumb>
  </ion-breadcrumbs>
```

i tried to add this breadcrumbs to my ionic 7 project. but its not working. give belove error message. please tell me to how to add ion-breadcrumb to my ionic angular project.

```
error NG8001: 'ion-breadcrumbs' is not a known element:
[ng] 1. If 'ion-breadcrumbs' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
[ng] 2. If 'ion-breadcrumbs' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

project package.json

```
"@ionic/angular": "^5.6.7",
"@angular/core": "^12.0.1",
```

refer the above code outputs.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to import `IonicModule` to `imports: []` if you are using stand-alone it could be like this:

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';


  @Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [IonicModule] <-- add this
  
})
```